# Showing a many-to-many relationship from in a GridView using the Repository pattern with Code First

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, webforms

I have a WebForms Application using a EF 4.1 - Code First for the Data Layer.  I have a many-to-many relationship.

```
public class Application
{
    public Application()
    {
        Administrators = new List<User>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Administrators { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Administrates = new List<Application>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    // Collections
    public virtual ICollection<Application> Administrates { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming the configuration is setup correctly, is there a way to implement an ObjectDataSource bound to a GridView in order to show who the administrators are for each application entity, with one record row per administrator.  Right now I am using a SqlDataSource with a View and StoredProcs to tackle this problem, but I would like to stick to one architecture pattern for my data layer.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial uses database first rather than code first but has an example that otherwise looks similar to what you're looking for and might have something useful:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/using-the-entity-framework-and-the-objectdatasource-control-part-3-sorting-and-filtering

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for.  How would I bind data that is coming from the GridView to the Delete, Insert, Update method?  `void Update(Guid applicationId, Guid userId)` and use those parameters to get the correct objects from the context object?